# Best approach in updating a useReducer state in reaction to a change in its initialArg

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

After the first render, the `useReducer` hook doesn't react to changes in its `initialArg` (second positional) argument. It makes it hard to properly sync it with an external value, without having to rely on an extra cycle by dispatching a reset action inside a `useEffect` hook.

I built a [minimal example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-cache-4vwwe?file=/src/App.js). It's a simple, formik-like, form provider. Here's what it looks like:

```
// App.js

const users = {
  1: {
    firstName: 'Paul',
    lastName: 'Atreides',
  },
  2: {
    firstName: 'Duncan',
    lastName: 'Idaho',
  },
};

const App = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(1);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Pick User</div>
      <button onClick={() => { setId(1); }} type="button">User 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => { setId(2); }} type="button">User 2</button>
      <FormProvider initialValues={users[id]}>
        <Editor />
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
// FormProvider.js

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_FIELD':
      return { ...state, [action.field]: action.value };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

const FormProvider = ({ children, initialValues }) => {
  const [values, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialValues);

  const handleChange = useCallback((evt) => {
    dispatch({
      field: evt.target.name,
      type: 'UPDATE_FIELD',
      value: evt.target.value,
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{ handleChange, values }}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
// Editor.js

const Editor = () => {
  const { handleChange, values } = useContext(FormContext);

  return (
    <>
      <div>First name:</div>
      <input
        name="firstName"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={values.firstName}
      />
      <div>First name:</div>
      <input
        name="lastName"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={values.lastName}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

If you open the demo and click on the *User 2* button, you'll notice that nothing happens. It's not surprising since we know that the `useReducer` hook gets initialised once using the provided `initialArg` argument and never reads its value again.

What I expect is the `useReducer` state to reflect the new `initialArg` prop, i.e. I want to see "Duncan" in the *First name* input after clicking on the *User 2* button.

From my point of vue, I can see two options:

**1. Passing a key prop to the `FormProvider` component.**

```
// App.js

const App = () => {
  // ...

  return (
    <>
      {/* ... */}
      <FormProvider key={id} initialValues={users[id]}>
        <Editor />
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

This will indeed fix the problem by destroying and re-creating the `FormProvider` component (and its children) every time the `id` changes. But it feels like a hack to me. Plus, it seems inefficient to rebuild that entire part of the tree (which is substantial in the real application) just to get that input values updated. However, this seems to be a common fix for such problems.

**2. Dispatch a RESET action whenever `initialValues` changes**

```
// FormProvider.js

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_FIELD':
      return { ...state, [action.field]: action.value };
    case 'RESET':
      return action.values;
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};
```

```
const FormProvider = ({ children, initialValues }) => {
  // ...

  const isFirstRenderRef = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFirstRenderRef.current) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'RESET',
        values: initialValues,
      });
    }
  }, [initialValues]);

  useEffect(() => {
    isFirstRenderRef.current = false;
  }, []);

 // ...
};
```

This will work as well, but, because it's happening inside a `useEffect` hook, it will require an extra cycle. It means that there'll be a moment where the form will contain stale values. If the user types at that moment, it could cause a race condition.

**3. Idea**

I read in [this article by Mark Erikson](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#render-behavior-edge-cases) that:

> Function components *may* call `setSomeState()` directly while rendering, as long as it's done conditionally and isn't going to execute every time this component renders. [...] If a function component queues a state update while rendering, React will immediately apply the state update and synchronously re-render that one component before moving onwards.

So it seems that I should be able to call `dispatch({ type: RESET, values: initialValues });` directly from the body of the function, under the condition that `initialValues` did change (I'd use a ref to keep track of its previous value). This should result in the state being updated in just one cycle. However, I couldn't get this to work.

——

***What do you think is best between option 1, 2 and (3). Any advice/guidance on how I should address this problem?***